# How to get a specific type object from an Object Vector in Java

Tags: java, object, vector, floating-point, integer

I have the following `Vector` and at runtime I want to pass it an `Integer`, `Character`, or `Float`:

```
public static Vector<Object> interestingValues = new Vector<Object>();
```

At the same time I want to get an `Integer`, `Float`, or `Character` from it, so there are two things:

- Will they retain the specific `Integer`/`Float`/`Character` type in the `Object` `Vector`, or they all will be stored in the form of `Object`?
- How can I retrieve `Integer` objects from this `Vector`?

Comment: When you have a collection of mixed types, its usually a better idea to define a class with fields of those types.

Comment: Vector is an old class, you should use the new Java Collections Framework. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting:

```
Integer i=(Integer)interestingValues.get(0);
```

In case you have multiple types of objects inside the Vector you could check the type using `instanceof`:

```
Object o=interestingValues.get(0);
 if (o instanceof Integer){
      Integer i=(Integer)o;
 }else if (o instanceof Long){
      Long l=(Long)o;
 }
```

The third thing you can do to avoid the need ov casting objects to a particular type is using a typed `Vector`:

```
Vector <Integer> integerVector=new Vector<Integer>();
integerVector.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
Integer i=integerVector.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the instanceof and casting :

```
if(interestingValues.get(0) instanceof Integer){
Integer value = (Integer) interestingValues.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Vector` only stores a *reference* to the object, not the object itself.

However since the (non generic) class is defined as storing references to `Object` you have to cast the stored references back to the original type before using them:

```
String s = (String)myVector.get(n);
```

That does of course require that you know in advance which particular type is stored in which element...

You could do:

```
Object o = myVector.get(n);
if (o instance String) {
    // do string stuff
} else if (o instanceof Integer) {
    // do integer stuff
} etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate and check for `Integer` instances, for example:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Object object:interestingValues) {
  if (object instanceof Integer)
     integers.add((Integer) object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to check the class of the object:

```
Object obj = myvector.get(0);
if( obj instanceof Integer) {
 Integer myInt = (Integer)obj;  
}
else if( obj instanceof Character ) {
  Integer myChar = (Character)obj; 
}
```

That's not a good design though. You might want to consider storing the objects in different vectors or using a comming representation (e.g. String) along with conversion.

Edit:

Since `Float`, `Integer` and the like all extend `Number` you might also just check for `obj instanceof Number` and then call `intValue()`, `doubleValue()` etc. on the casted object if all you need is the number and not the type.

Answer (score 0):

instanceof checks the "isa" releationship.  If you want to be 100% sure of the class, use getClass().  here is a long winded example:

```
public class Blue
{
  private String yargh;

  public Blue()
  {
    yargh = "blue";
  }

  public Blue(final String value)
  {
    yargh = StringUtils.defaultString(value);
  }

  public void println()
  {
    System.out.println(yargh);
  }
}

public class Berry extends Blue
{
  public Berry()
  {
    super("blueberry");
  }
}

... blah blah blah
Vector<Object> stuff = new ... blah blah blah
stuff.add(new blue());
stuff.add(new berry());

Iterator<Object> iterator = stuff.iterator();
Object minemine;

// this calls println on two objects.
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
  minemine = iterator.next();
  if (minemine instanceof Blue)
  {
    Blue bluemine = (Blue)minemine;
    bluemine.println();
  }
}

// This calls println for the Blue object, but not the Berry object.
iterator = stuff.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
  minemine = iterator.next();
  if (minemine.getClass() == Blue.class)
  {
    Blue bluemine= (Berry)minemine;
    bluemine.println();
  }
}
```

*Caveat emptor:* I did not complile the code above.